# Как доработать регулярное выражение

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько вариантов написания ФИО авторов:

```
a = ['Журавская М.А.', 'Тарасян В.С.', 'Иванов И.И.']
b = ['Тарасян Владимир Сергеевич', 'Полушкин Алексей Яковлевич']
c = ['ZHURAVSKAYA Marina', 'TARASYAN Vladimir']
d = ['ZHURAVSKAYA M.', 'TARASYAN V.', 'Ivanov I.']
```

Их нужно подставить в формулу, например:

```
^AЖуравская^BМ. А.
^AИванов^BИ. И.   
^AТарасян^BВ. С.
^AПолушкин^BА. Я.
^ATARASYAN^BV.
^AZHURAVSKAYA^BM.
^AIvanov^BI.
```

Раньше я пользовалась вот такой переменной:

```
authors_b = [re.sub(r'(\w+)\s+(\w)(?:\.\s*?|\w{1,})\s*?(\w)(?:\.|\w{1,})', r'^A\1^B\2. \3.', x) for x in authors_a]
```

К сожалению, она учитывает вариант, если в ФИО автора три слова. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как доработать переменную, чтобы она обрабатывала и вариант с двумя словами.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить. Напишите, как должен выглядеть результат, для всех исходных данных.

Comment: @Lecron, добавила примеры

Comment: Даже если вы сделаете этот regex(это возможно), ваш ответ будет выглядеть как: `^ATARASYAN^BV. (None).` возможно без None, потому что в подстановке: `\2. \3.` - вот эту вторую часть с `\3.` вы все равно оставляете. и там появится как минимум пробел + точка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def conv_name(name):
    last,_,rest = name.partition(' ')
    rest = rest.replace('.', '. ')
    first,_,patron = rest.partition(' ')
    first = first[0] + '.'
    res = f'^A{last}^B{first}'
    if patron:
        res += f' {patron[0]}.'
    return res


In [38]: [conv_name(name) for x in [a,b,c,d] for name in x]
Out[38]:
['^AЖуравская^BМ. А.',
 '^AТарасян^BВ. С.',
 '^AИванов^BИ. И.',
 '^AТарасян^BВ. С.',
 '^AПолушкин^BА. Я.',
 '^AZHURAVSKAYA^BM.',
 '^ATARASYAN^BV.',
 '^AZHURAVSKAYA^BM.',
 '^ATARASYAN^BV.',
 '^AIvanov^BI.']
```

Comment: начинаю подозревать, что Вы - волшебник!!! Спасибо Вам огромное, что постоянно помогаете мне.

Answer (score 1):

Все равно не совсем понятно, но предположу, что с небольшими доработками, вам подойдет этот вариант:

```
import string

s = ['Тарасян Владимир Сергеевич', 'Журавская М.А.', 'Фамилия']
for author in s:
    tokens = [f'^{c}{w}' for c, w in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, author.split())]
    line = ''.join(tokens).replace('.', '. ').rstrip()
    print(line)
```

Работает, пока количество слов меньше, чем букв в алфавите.

```
^AТарасян^BВладимир^CСергеевич
^AЖуравская^BМ. А.
^AФамилия
```

PS. Считаю, что в большинстве случаев, если проблема решается регулярными выражениями, у разработчика становится уже две проблемы.